# Find contour of non-binary image

Tags: opencv, contour, image-segmentation

I am currently trying to wrap my head around the idea of computing the contour of an image.  There are many different types of algorithms that exist.  Some say that the contour should be applied after edge detection.  There is information stating that the contour can be computed on gray scale images and others say only binary images.  I am looking to find out the process of contour tracing on a colored image.  I am wanting to understand the more general concept:

Is an object first "cut out" from the natural image to be examined?

Does the image need to be binary where the object is in a silhouette format?

Much data can be lost when turning an image into a binary image, how is this compensated?

How is the object recognized in the habitat of the natural scene?

Any links to documentation or personal knowledge would be much appreciated!  I can't seem to find much information on these concepts.  Also, if there is a particular contour algorithm that has excellent documentation, a link would be very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: in contour extraction the aim is to find some "target contour" and it includes several tasks, one is basically to find connected components in a binary image (and connected components within other connected components), which is the task performed by cv::findContours. So your task is to binarize the image in a way that your desired contours are separated from the rest. This might sound like the tougher work has to be figured out by yourself (HOW to separate the objects in the image), but findContours still is a mighty tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally realized that I was mixing together two closely related concepts which caused some confusion.  There is a difference between border tracing and finding a contour.  In border tracing, I found that yes, the object looking to be traced needs to be a binary image.  If the object is part of a natural scene, it should be removed from the natural scene and be processed separately.  After the border has been traced, the result is the contour of the object (just the outline of the image and nothing more).  As far as edges within an object, some border tracing algorithms consider the edges, others do not.  This is only one method of finding a contour.

My objective was to create a contour of an image that contained missing borders (resolving the issue of computer vision and the gestalt principle of closure).  Border tracing will **not** solve this issue.  I instead looked at an active contour model (snakes) which will allow for new borders to be created and existing borders to be outlined based on the energy within the image.  This satisfied my objective of finding a contour of an image as well as closing opened borders.